# Writing a Simple AutoHotkey Script (press a key every X second on desktop)

Tags: autohotkey

I need to press any useless key (like F11) every 5 minutes or less to keep the windows active (if it became inactive for 10 minutes it will lock-out).

But I need the key to be pressed on the desktop (so it doesn't effect any open windows).

I have tried

```
Loop
{
   ControlSend, {F11}, WindowsApplication1
   Sleep, 100000
}
```

but doesn't seem to work.

thanks.

edit: my current script:

```
#NoTrayIcon

NumLock::Run Calc.exe

PrintScreen::Run "C:\Windows\Sysnative\SnippingTool.exe"

; When I press Insert, I want to Show Desktop
Insert::Run, "%A_APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Shows Desktop.lnk"

; When I press Pause/ Break, I want to Lock the Computer
Pause::DllCall("LockWorkStation")

#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
~MButton::Send !{Up}
#IfWinActive

Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the cursor every X minutes:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, MoveMouse

MoveMouse:
    If ( A_TimeIdle > 300000 ) {
      MouseMove, 1 , 1,, R
      MouseMove, -1,-1,, R
    }
Return
```

Code adopted from [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/13510-move-mouse-when-not-in-use-to-disable-screensaver/?p=88261).

Comment: It didn't work, should it be in a separated script file? because I appended it to an existing script.

Comment: Depends on what else is in your script. Posting the whole thing would be of certain help.

Comment: This is exactly what I would do, too.

Comment: @Unorthodox What mechanism exactly is causing your session to be locked?

Comment: no activity for 10 minutes screensaver activate, and enter password to log-in.

Comment: Is mousemove moving oyur mouse at all? Try to make a new script and just put the following line in it and tell us if it moves your mouse: MouseMove, 1000 , 1000,, R

Comment: update: it works now, the code must be on top of the script, if it was in the bottom it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely nothing that should require Autohotkey.
Just disable your screensaver.
Rightclick your desktop
Click Personalize (Vista/7/8) or Properties (XP)
Go to the screensaver options
Disable the screensaver

You might also wanna disable stuff like "turn off display after x minutes", "go to sleep  after x minutes" and "turn of harddrives after x minutes".
You'll find that in the poweroptions. There is a button in the screensaver options to get  there...

edit: Another way of disabling the screensaver using autohotkey would be the following script:

```
#Persistent
Menu, Tray, Icon, User32.dll, 4
Menu, Tray, Tip, Screen Saver Disabled !!!
OnExit, ScreenSaveActivate
DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", Int,17, Int,0, UInt,NULL, Int,2)
SetTimer, CheckScreenSaveActive, 999
Return

CheckScreenSaveActive:
DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", Int,16, UInt,NULL, "UInt *",SSACTIVE, Int,0)
If SSACTIVE
   DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", Int,17, Int,0, UInt,NULL, Int,2)
Return

ScreenSaveActivate:
DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", Int,17, Int,1, UInt,NULL, Int,2)
ExitApp
Return
```

which was created by SKAN from the ahk forums.

Comment: I can't, requires admin permission. (company's PC)

Comment: But you can run autohotkey scripts? oO

Comment: Can you tell me what does the last script exactly do?

Comment: ATH? Well if this script doesn't work I can't really help you. I think you will need more priviledges to go on. If sending keystrokes is the only thing that works, then just send Ctrl or Shift every minute...

Comment: AHK **, Keystroke or mouse move/clicks.

Comment: Then I don't really understand why MCL's solution doesn't work for you.